# Is Bitcoin core V.0.9 not updated on PPA ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin-core, ubuntu

[Version 0.9 of Bitcoin-Qt](https://bitcoin.org/en/download) just came out. When will [ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin](https://launchpad.net/~bitcoin/+archive/bitcoin) be updated? In the meanwhile, any steps showing how to upgrade are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PPA is on 0.8.6, which is very recent (just missing 0.9, but I'm gonna hopefully upload that today). What you're referring to is the Ubuntu package distribution, which is very, very, very out of date (to the point of it being largely non-functional).

Comment: Unfortunately, 0.9 is having build trouble for Saucy and Trusty https://launchpad.net/~bitcoin/+archive/bitcoin/+packages

Comment: I'm confused. The OP has linked to the PPA (and has not edited the post as far as I can see), but you seem to indicate that the OP is referring to something other than the PPA.

Answer (score 1):

0.9.0 was posted earlier today.

Answer (score 0):

I second this. The PPA is very outdated (I think using < 0.4). The only way I could think of manually upgrading would be to pull the latest Git Tag for 0.9.0 and re-make (compile) from source.